# How can I protect a logging object from the garbage collector in a multiprocessing process?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, garbage-collection, multiprocessing

I create a couple of worker processes using Python's Multiprocessing module 2.6.
In each worker I use the standard logging module (with log rotation and file per worker) 
to keep an eye on the worker. I've noticed that after a couple of hours that no more 
events are written to the log. The process doesn't appear to crash and still responds
to commands via my queue. Using lsof I can see that the log file is no longer open.
I suspect the log object may be killed by the garbage collector, if so is there a way
that I can mark it to protect it?

Comment: I really doubt the GC has anything to do with it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @THC4k. This doesn't seem like a GC issue. I'll give you my reasons why, and I'm sure somebody will vote me down if I'm wrong (if so, please leave a comment pointing out my error!).

If you're using CPython, it primarily uses reference counting, and objects are destroyed immediately when the ref count goes to zero (since 2.0, supplemental garbage collection is also provided to handle the case of circular references). Keep a reference to your log object and it won't be destroyed.

If you're using Jython or IronPython, the underlying VM does the garbage collection. Again, keep a reference and the GC shouldn't touch it.

Either way, it seems that either you're not keeping a reference to an object you need to keep alive, or you have some other error.

Comment: CPython does have a mark and sweep garbage collector. It uses reference counting as a performance improvement, so it doesn't have to mark and sweep non circular data structures.  Either way the solution is the same if you don't want something to be collected keep a reference to it.

Comment: I have not tracked the problem down yet, but as far as I can tell it appears that the reporting of the file handle getting lost via lsof (htop) was incorrect. I think there's a bug in htop/lsof integration :)

Answer (score 0):

```
http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__
```

According to this documentation the **del**() method is called on object destruction and you can at this point create a reference to the object to prevent it from being collected.  I am not sure how to do this, hopefully this gives you some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `gc.collect()` immediately after fork() to see if that causes the log to be closed. But it's not likely garbage collection would take effect only after a few hours.